# CakePHP: How do you avoid the use of a template when rendering JSON?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm presently working with a new project in CakePHP, and when I add a json request to a controller, CakePHP looks for a matching view template in the views folder. This behavior would be fine for regular pages, but every single one of my json view templates is *completely empty*. I use a "json" layout that looks like this:

```
<?php
Configure::write('debug', 0);
echo json_encode($json_output);
?>
```

I realize a partial solution might be to simply "touch" a file for every json view that I create, but that involves SSHing into the server and doing a lot of overhead stuff. Is there a way to simply tell CakePHP to use *just the layout* for a given view?

Comment: Red Ping; see below for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable a view in cake.

http://www.sethcardoza.com/posts/view/31/title/disabling-layouts-and-views-in-cakephp

Comment: Please note, this goes with pretty much all PHP frameworks. They normally have some means to disable a view for a controller.